# Unexpected behavior of nth-child selector

Tags: javascript, html

The CSS `nth-child()` selector returns expected results for html and body nodes on Chrome.

Go to a website like https://web.ics.purdue.edu/~gchopra/class/public/pages/webdesign/05_simple.html and do:

```
document.querySelectorAll('body:nth-child(1)')
```

The returned value is null when it should be an `h1`.

Comment: Another approach:
document.querySelectorAll('body')[0].firstElementChild;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body:nth-child(1)` means to select an element whose tag is `body` and is also the first child of its parent.

To select the 1st child of the `body` tag, you need to use the `>` operator to separate the selectors: `body > :nth-child(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `:nth-child` pseudo class has to be used on the child.

So `body > :nth-child(1)` is what you are looking for.